# /etc/network/interfaces missing on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, networking

I am confused by Raspbian network configuration. I'd like to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to setup the loopback interface to start automatically but I cannot find the configuration file.

```
root@raspberrypi:/# cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

This is the content of `/etc/network`:

```
root@raspberrypi:/# ls -al /etc/network
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root 4096 Jun 25 20:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 102 root root 4096 Jun 28 13:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May  6 23:16 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May  6 22:38 if-post-down.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May  6 22:38 if-pre-up.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 May  6 23:16 if-up.d
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   12 May  6 22:18 run -> /run/network
```

It's worth nothing that my Raspberry Pi automatically connects to the ethernet network and picks up an IP address via DHCP, so there must be some other piece of configuration elsewhere I cannot find.

Where is network configuration located in Raspbian? From some googling I'd say it's on `/etc/network/interfaces` but what I see on my machine seems to suggest something different.

To add more information, this is my `uname -a` output:

```
mario@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

and this is the output of `ps -ef` after I manually added `/etc/network/interfaces` with the configuration I needed, which is working fine.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:07 init [2]
root         2     0  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:03 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:07 [rcu_preempt]
root         8     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root         9     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root        11     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        12     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        13     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [perf]
root        14     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        15     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root        16     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
root        17     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        18     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root        19     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:47 [kworker/0:1]
root        20     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod]
root        21     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        22     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        23     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsiod]
root        29     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root        30     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [VCHIQ-0]
root        31     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [VCHIQr-0]
root        32     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [VCHIQs-0]
root        33     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [iscsi_eh]
root        34     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [dwc_otg]
root        35     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [DWC Notificatio]
root        37     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [VCHIQka-0]
root        38     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]
root        40     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:01 [mmcqd/0]
root        42     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]
root        43     2  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       158     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 udevd --daemon
root       295   158  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 udevd --daemon
root       301   158  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 udevd --daemon
root      1547     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:02:05 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i eth0 -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1576     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:21 /usr/sbin/ifplugd -i lo -q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I
root      1633     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
root      2067     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
root      2133     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron
102       2141     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
avahi     2178     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [raspberrypi.local]
avahi     2179  2178  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
tp       2218     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:27 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 104:107
root      2245     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
nobody    2269     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/thd --daemon --triggers /etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d/ --socket /var/run/thd.socket --pidfile /var/run/thd.pid --user nobody /dev/input/event*
root      2302     1  0 Jun28 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
root      2303     1  0 Jun28 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
root      2304     1  0 Jun28 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
root      2305     1  0 Jun28 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
root      2306     1  0 Jun28 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
root      2307     1  0 Jun28 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
root      2308     1  0 Jun28 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
root      2906     2  0 Jun29 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u2:0]
root      3100     2  0 Jun29 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root      3578     2  0 17:17 ?        00:00:01 [kworker/u2:1]
mario     3628     1  3 20:50 ?        00:00:04 mosh-server new -s -c 8 -l LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 -l LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
mario     3629  3628  1 20:50 pts/0    00:00:01 -bash
mario     3650  3629  0 20:51 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Comment: Can you please add the output from  `uname -a` and `ps -ef` to your question.

Comment: I added it. Please note that the output of `ps -ef` has been taken after I manually added `/etc/network/interfaces` and everything is working as expected. I am still not sure about how everything could work earlier with that file missing

Comment: +1 same build as @mariosangiorgio and `interfaces` also missing

Comment: Were you using your Pi with headless or do you connect with a monitor and a keyboard? @mariosangiorgio

Comment: I've always ran it headless

Answer (score 5):

reinstall ifupdown package

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ifupdown
sudo apt-get install ifupdown
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `nano`, in a terminal type:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interface
```

That will list the setup info you are looking for.

Comment: You have hit one of my pet peeves, why oh why would you ever use sudo to run an editor as root when you have sudoedit? `sudoedit /etc/network/interface` or if you don't like the default editor `EDITOR=nano sudoedit /etc/network/interface` uses nano.

Comment: @hildred: I see your point - but it's not only the edit command you have to invoke as root. I prefer to have a clean and identical syntax all the time I invoke a command as root :-)

Comment: @framp, I use sudoedit whenever editing any file as root except for kerberos keytabs, when invoked from debconf or sudo is not yet installed. I find that this results in great consistency.